# Как открыть приложение Яндекс.Карты при клике на ссылку в Android?

Tags: javascript, html, android, яндекс-карты

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в браузере открывалось приложение Яндекс.Карты, с местом навигации (координаты)?

Comment: В документации к Яндекс-картам все подробно написано. Что бы отрывались прямо Ядекс.Карты, не помню. НО точно можно было сделать так, что бы открывался сразу Яндекс.Навигатор с маршрутом. 
Однако для корректной работы геолокации, вам необходимо https-соединение.

Answer (score 2):

Используй специальный протокол `yandexmaps`. К примеру ссылка может выглядеть вот так:

```html
<a href="yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12">Открыть карту
Москвы в приложении Яндекс.Карты</a>
```

Comment: Не работает, попробовал

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян открой браузер в телефоне и набери указанную ссылку в строке для url. Должно открыться приложение "Яндекс.карты".

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в ссылку слово maps.  Между https:// и yandex.ru/maps/......
То есть если URL ссылки выглядит так:
https://yandex.ru/maps/......
То он откроется в браузере.
А если изменить и написать так:
https://maps.yandex.ru/maps/......
То откроется в приложении Яндекс карты
Это я про телефоны на android