# Открытие Яндекс Карт с Telegram

Tags: telegram, aiogram, бот

При разработке бота в телеграмме столкнулся с проблемой. Я беру две координаты и с помощью `WebAppInfo` открываю мини сайт в телеграмме и оттуда могу сразу перейти в яндекс карты с уже проложенным маршрутом. НООО это срабатывает только на ios, если же я пытаюсь это же сделать на android он сначала перекидывает меня в браузер, т.к. по факту это является web url, а потом в приложение Яндекс Карты в Google Play, но оттуда если открыть маршрут не сохраняется.

`Url`:

```
yan_maps_navigate_url = 'https://yandex.ru/maps/?rtext={0},{1}~{2},{3}&rtt=auto'
```

Смотрел [Как открыть приложение Яндекс.Карты при клике на ссылку в Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046523/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-android) эту статью, но она не помогла.

Знаю что можно открывать Яндекс карты сразу по ссылке, но мне это не подходит, нужно чтобы у пользователя был так сказать предпросмотр веб версии в телеграм, а потом уже после нажатия поехали открывалось мобильное приложение